# Impressão DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Preciso imprimir as colunas selecionadas em um DataGridView. 
Não posso gerar imagem, porque são muitas colunas (15 ao todo) e não aparecem todas na tela. 
Posso fazer a impressão em paisagem ou retrato, desde que apareçam todas as informações. Os dados não são muitos que serão selecionados (máximo de 10), mas não posso deixar de imprimir todas as colunas. 
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer criar uma opção que imprimi todas as colunas e outras somente as selecionadas?

Comment: Todas as colunas, mas apenas as linhas selecionadas. Uma impressão só.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido:
Utilizei o DGVPrinter.

O botão ficou assim:

```
private void btPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();
            printer.PrintDataGridView(dataGridView1);

        }
```

Adicionei a classe DGVPrinter.cs https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBxpfm3kmmgci1aSnZ6T0RudGc/view ao projeto e, no form do datagrid coloquei ele em using.

Imprime em paisagem e retrato, basta selecionar na impressora e, se quiser selecionar as colunas a serem impressas, basta mandar imprimir seleção.